# What is invalid in the following JSON request data and how to make it a valid JSON data request?

Tags: php, json, validation, request

I've following JSON request which after checking in [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) says **"INVALID"**

```
{"groupId":"","photo":[{"fileURL":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Zi70cZ
LLRHS3UF5PSSxN","filename":"Image 12 August 2015 12:34
PM.jpg"}],"status_info":"test image"}
```

It gives following error which I am not understanding:

```
Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 12]
Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 16]
```

Can some one  please let me know what is wrong with the JSON request data and how to make it a valid JSON data request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a newline in `fileURL` value?

Comment: newline characrers in both fields make in invalid

Comment: you can use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json object

Comment: There is a free to use website called `jsonlint.com` use it and answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

This is valid in http://jsonlint.com/

```
{
    "groupId": "",
    "photo": [
        {
        "fileURL": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Zi70cZLLRHS3UF5PSSxN",
        "filename": "Image 12 August 2015 12:3PM.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "status_info": "test image"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is valid json..

{"groupId":"","photo":[{"fileURL":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Zi70cZLLRHS3UF5PSSxN","filename":"Image 12 August 2015 12:34 PM.jpg"}],"status_info":"test image"}

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is incorrect because of the line breaks.

You should remove them in your case, or replace them with '\n' if you do need the line break.

This is a very useful tool for checking JSON strings http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Close, but you had line breaks in `fileURL` and `filename`. Removing those validates your JSON, like so:

```
{
    "groupId": "",
    "photo": [
        {
            "fileURL": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Zi70cZLLRHS3UF5PSSxN",
            "filename": "Image 12 August 2015 12:34PM.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "status_info": "test image"
}
```

For future reference, [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a great tool for validating JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string contains a newline character in file url and file name values. Basically in a JSON string the special characters like \n, \t, \b has to be skipped.

```js
{  
   "groupId":"",
   "photo":[  
      {  
         "fileURL":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Zi70cZLLRHS3UF5PSSxN",
         "filename":"Image 12 August 2015 12:34 PM.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "status_info":"test image"
}
```

If the newline character is unintentional, then while forming the JSON make sure your logic trims all the newline characters in the value.